# 3d matrix dynamic allocation error C2036: 'void *'

Tags: c++, c

I have a MPI project and I'm supposed to convert it in cuda.

The problem is simple, the project use this code to allocate 3d matrix of different types.

```
void ***Matrix3Allocate(Point3 offset, Point3 size, int dataSize){
    void *matrix_data;
    void **matrix_data_ptr;
    void ***matrix;
    int nb_elements = Matrix3GetNbElements(size);

    message("Allocate matrix (%d,%d,%d) %d ko (plus pointeurs : %d ko)", 
            size.x, size.y, size.z, nb_elements * dataSize / 1024,
            size.x * ( 1 + size.y ) * sizeof(void*) / 1024);

    matrix = (void ***)secure_malloc(size.x * sizeof(void**));
    matrix_data_ptr = (void **)secure_malloc(size.x * size.y * sizeof(void*));
    matrix_data = (void *)secure_malloc(nb_elements * dataSize);

    matrix -= offset.x;
    for(int x = offset.x; x < offset.x + size.x; x++)
        matrix[x] = matrix_data_ptr + size.y * (x - offset.x) - offset.y;

    for(int x = offset.x; x < offset.x + size.x; x++)
        for(int y = offset.y; y < offset.y + size.y; y++)
            matrix[x][y] = matrix_data +
                    ((x - offset.x) * size.y * size.z +
                (y - offset.y) * size.z - offset.z) * dataSize;

    return matrix;
}
```

When compiling I have an error C2036: 'void *' unknown size on this part :

```
matrix[x][y] = matrix_data + ((x - offset.x) * size.y * size.z +
               (y - offset.y) * size.z - offset.z) * dataSize;
```

I understand why the compiler is screaming but this code was working before (probably with a different compiler) and I would like to change a minimum of code.

Could I make it work with a simple flag?

Is there a minimal modification that could make it compile without error?

The obvious (big) solution is to use c++ templates, but this was a C project so if there is an other (simpler) solution in C...

Thanks.

Comment: It gives an error since nowhere do you give a concrete type to anything.  You have to, at some point, tell the compiler whether that `void*` points to an `int`, `char`, `double`, whatever.

Comment: the elements in your matrices variables (matrix, matrix_data_ptr, etc.) are void*. that doesn't make sense as matrix data. maybe int, float, or double pointers instead?

Comment: I understand that, but this function is used like the malloc function, the size of the type is given. 

Example :

blocksCoeff = (CoeffBlock ***)Matrix3Allocate( Point3i(1, 1, 1), packedListSize, sizeof(CoeffBlock) );

Comment: *but this code was working before (probably with a different compiler)*  -- What broken compiler was this??

Comment: The files I was given are from 2006 and the makefile mentioned "mpicc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the addition to a void pointer (`matrix_data +`...)
As far as I interpret your code, it should work by casting it to `char *` first.
So try

```
matrix [x][y] = ((char *) matrix_data) + ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this line gives an error:

```
matrix[x][y] = matrix_data + ((x - offset.x) * size.y * size.z +
                 (y - offset.y) * size.z - offset.z) * dataSize;
```

is that once you add a value to the pointer, the compiler needs to know the concrete type so that the correct "stride" is made to the next element.  Since everything is void*, the compiler has no choice except to give you the error.

If your goal is to increment by `sizeof(char)`, then you need char pointers.  The easiest fix would be to use a `char *` that points to `matrix_data`:

```
char *myMatrix = (char *)matrix_data;
matrix[x][y] = myMatrix + ((x - offset.x) * size.y * size.z +
               (y - offset.y) * size.z - offset.z) * dataSize;
```